# Getting Channel Divinity through multiclassing in 4e?

Tags: dnd-4e

I thought I read something about different ways to get Channel Divinity through multiclassing in D&D 4th Edition, but I can't remember where I found it or if I found it at all.  I'm curious about whether or not there's a way for a character multiclassing into a divine class (e.g., cleric or invoker) to get the Channel Divinity class feature without paragon multiclassing.  I know there are multiclass feats like Divine Channeler that grant use of Channel Divinity powers, but I think Divine Channeler makes you treat those powers as dailies instead of encounter powers, so I'm more curious about multiclass feats that treat Channel Divinity like how it is for a full divine character.

Answer (score 1):

Your analysis is correct. You cannot get *per encounter* use of Channel Divinity without paragon multiclassing (all of the Channel of X feats are require paragon MC).

There is no feat based multiclass that provides Channel divinity in the way that you are looking. You *could* hybrid with one of the divine classes and get it, but that's a similar (if not more severe) commitment as PMC.

Overall, this is as intended. Generally with MC type features you get encounter stuff daily and at-will stuff per encounter.

Answer (score -4):

In 5E you get Channel Divinity as a Palladin level ability.  So if you multi-class to Palladin and work it high enough you can get it.

Comment: You are talking about a different version of the rules, and it is generally not safe with DnD in particular to make any assumptions about similarities